# parse multiple dates using dateutil

Tags: python, parsing, python-dateutil

I am trying to parse multiple dates from a string in Python with the help of this code,

```
from dateutil.parser import _timelex, parser
a = "Approve my leave from first half of 12/10/2012 to second half of 20/10/2012 "
p = parser()
info = p.info
def timetoken(token):
  try:
    float(token)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    pass
  return any(f(token) for f in (info.jump,info.weekday,info.month,info.hms,info.ampm,info.pertain,info.utczone,info.tzoffset))

def timesplit(input_string):
  batch = []
  for token in _timelex(input_string):
    if timetoken(token):
      if info.jump(token):
        continue
      batch.append(token)
    else:
      if batch:
        yield " ".join(batch)
        batch = []
  if batch:
    yield " ".join(batch)

for item in timesplit(a):
  print "Found:", item
  print "Parsed:", p.parse(item)
```

and the codes is taking *second half* from the string as second date and giving me this error,

```
raise ValueError, "unknown string format"

ValueError: unknown string format
```

when i change 'second half' to 'third half' or 'forth half' then it is working all fine.

Can any one help me to parse this string ?

Answer (score 3):

Your parser couldn't handle the `"second"` found by `timesplit`,if you set the `fuzzy` param to be `True`, it doesn't break but nor does it produce anything meaningful.

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
for item in timesplit(StringIO(a)):
    print "Found:", item
    print "Parsed:", p.parse(StringIO(item),fuzzy=True)
```

*out:*

```
Found: 12 10 2012
Parsed: 2012-12-10 00:00:00
Found: second
Parsed: 2013-01-11 00:00:00
Found: 20 10 2012
Parsed: 2012-10-20 00:00:00
```

You have to fix the timesplitting or handle the errors:

*opt1:*

lose the `info.hms` from `timetoken`

*opt2:*

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
for item in timesplit(StringIO(a)):
    print "Found:", item
    try:
        print "Parsed:", p.parse(StringIO(item))
    except ValueError:
        print 'Not Parsed!'
```

*out:*

```
Found: 12 10 2012
Parsed: 2012-12-10 00:00:00
Found: second
Not Parsed!
Parsed: Found: 20 10 2012
Parsed: 2012-10-20 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need only dates, could extract it with regex and works with dates.

```
a = "Approve my leave from first half of 12/10/2012 to second half of 20/10/2012 "

import re
pattern = re.compile('\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}')
pattern.findall(a)
['12/10/2012', '20/10/2012']
```